# ViewModel Until test case error Provider members initialize error

Tags: android, junit, mocking

> I am getting provider initial error while trying to run viewModel test case

> Provider members initialize error
> com.venuetize.vzsportsapp.providers.Provider$ProviderException: Provider members initialize error
>
> View Model test class

```
private val sigInUseCase = mockk<SigInUseCase>()
private val getUserProfileDataUseCase = mockk<GetUserProfileDataUseCase>()
private val updateLocalUserProfileUseCase = mockk<UpdateLocalUserProfileUseCase>()
private val networkConnectivityService = mockk<NetworkConnectivityService>()
private val viewModel = VstLoginViewModel(
    sigInUseCase,
    getUserProfileDataUseCase,
    updateLocalUserProfileUseCase,
    networkConnectivityService
)

@Test
fun `email state() - blank value`() {
    viewModel.handleEvent(VstLoginEvent.InputChanged(inputType = VstInputType.Password("")))
    val stateValue=viewModel.state.password
    stateValue.shouldBe("")
}

@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = Modifier.PRIVATE)
```

internal class VstLoginViewModel(
private val signInUseCase: SigInUseCase,
private val getUserProfileDataUseCase: GetUserProfileDataUseCase,
private val updateLocalUserProfileUseCase: UpdateLocalUserProfileUseCase,
networkConnectivityService: NetworkConnectivityService
) : VstBaseViewModel(networkConnectivityService) {

```
val state = VstLoginViewStateHolder(authScreenState = WidgetFwkManager.authScreenConfig)

private val _effectFlow = MutableSharedFlow<VstLoginEffect>()
val effectFlow = _effectFlow.asSharedFlow()

override fun retryAction(isPullToRefresh: Boolean) {}


fun handleEvent(event: VstLoginEvent) {
    launchOnMainDispatcher {
        when (event) {
            is VstLoginEvent.CreateAccountClicked -> _effectFlow.emit(VstLoginEffect.OpenSignUpScreen)
            VstLoginEvent.ForgotPasswordClicked -> _effectFlow.emit(VstLoginEffect.OpenForgotPasswordScreen)
            is VstLoginEvent.InputChanged -> handleInputChange(input = event.inputType)
            VstLoginEvent.SingInClicked -> {
                logAnalytics(analyticsEvent = VstAnalyticsManager.VstAnalyticsEvent.LoginByVz)
                logMParticleEvent(event = VstMParticleManager.AnalyticsEvent.LoginSignInClicked)
                validateForm()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun handleInputChange(input: VstInputType) {
    when (input) {
        is VstInputType.Email -> state.email = input.value
        is VstInputType.Password -> state.password = input.value
        else -> {}
    }

}

private fun validateForm() {
    if (networkConnectivityService?.networkStatus?.value == NetworkStatus.Disconnected) {
        showNoInternetConnectionError()
        return
    }
    val message = when {
        state.email.isBlank() || state.password.isBlank() -> "Email and password are required"
        !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(state.email).matches() -> "Invalid email address"
        else -> ""
    }
    if (message.isNotBlank()) error(message = message)
    else login()
}

private fun login() {
    launchOnIODispatcher {
        state.isLoading = true
        signInUseCase(username = state.email, password = state.password)
            .onSuccess { profile ->
                getUserProfileDataUseCase()
                    .onSuccess { profileHolder ->
                        updateLocalUserProfileUseCase.byProfile(
                            profile = profile,
                            profileHolder = profileHolder
                        )
                    }
                logMParticleEvent(
                    event = VstMParticleManager.AnalyticsEvent.LoginSuccessful(
                        method = "standard"
                    )
                )
                state.isLoading = false
                _effectFlow.emit(VstLoginEffect.CloseAuthFlow)
            }
            .onFailure { t ->
                error(throwable = t)
                state.isLoading = false
            }
    }
}
```

}

> Error

> Provider members initialize error
> com.venuetize.vzsportsapp.providers.Provider$ProviderException: Provider members initialize error
> at app//com.venuetize.vzsportsapp.providers.Provider$ProviderException.(Provider.kt)
> at app//com.venuetize.vzsportsapp.providers.Provider.getMenuProvider(Provider.kt:15)
> at app//com.venuetize.vzsportsapp.utils.base.VstBaseViewModel.(VstBaseViewModel.kt:36)
> at app//com.venuetize.vzsportsapp.ui.authorization.login.VstLoginViewModel.(VstLoginViewModel.kt:24)
> at app//com.venuetize.vzsportsapp.viewModel.VstLoginViewModelTest.(VstLoginViewModelTest.kt:19)